Unable to fill autocompletion (TexShop)
I have the following problem when I use TexShop.
In this simple text I have an equation with a label

When I want to add a reference to it I start typing \eqref{eq:  and then I press fn+F5 to get suggestions. I can move through them with arrows, but I can't select any of them. If I press enter, for example, it doesn't type anything.
If something is not clear let me know.
Thanks in advance
